# How to uninstall packages in /usr folder

Tags: ubuntu, unix, ubuntu-18.04

I have certain packages files in local bin such as python2.7, jupyter notebooks, reaver etc which I don't want at all. I tried doing

sudo apt-get remove command but it said that the packages have not been installed , and so not removed.

But when I type reaver on terminal it shows that it is installed.

How do I remove these unwanted files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove software
Using apt from command line
Just use the command

```
sudo apt-get remove package_name
```

If you want to also remove user data and configuration files

```
sudo apt-get purge package_name
```

Using --auto-remove parameter will also remove package dependencies.

Using dpkg from command line
Just use the command

```
sudo dpkg -r package_name
```

To remove a package and its configuration files

```
sudo dpkg -P package_name
```

Files in your home folder are not part of the package so they will stay on your system until you remove them by yourself.